# How to make a character walk in GameMaker

Tags: game-maker, game-maker-studio-2

I am making a game with my friend and I'm sorting out some scripts. When I was writing the script for walking, I got the error message below. What did I do wrong?

[image: The error code]

Here is my code:

[image: My code]

Comment: Error messages should be shared as text, not images. This helps improve the search hits your post gets, bringing more eyeballs to it. It also makes your post more accessible to folks who use translator or screen reader software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you see an error message like:

> `Variable [variable_name] not set before reading it.`

it means your program is trying to change the value of a variable that doesn't exist. You shall declare a variable in the **Create Event** so that other object scripts can use and manipulate its value [thereafter](https://manual.yoyogames.com/The_Asset_Editors/Object_Properties/Object_Events.htm).

More precisely, you are setting the value of the built-in instance variable `x` relative to `-move_speed`. If it were GML Code, it would be equivalent to:

```
x -= move_speed;
```

Unfortunately, it seems that `move_speed` is unknown to the current object. The **Key Press Event** cannot decrease `x` by `move_speed` because it has no idea what `move_speed` is.

You can fix this by adding a **Create Event** to the object and including a [**Assign Variable** GML Visual block](https://manual.yoyogames.com/index.htm#t=Drag_And_Drop%2FDrag_And_Drop_Reference%2FCommon%2FAssign_Variable.htm), in which you define `move_speed` as a new instance variable that can later be referenced in other blocks or scripts.

Comment: I did what you said I added the variable in the create event but this happened 
___________________________________________
ERROR in
action number 1
of Create Event
for object charactertest_obj:

Variable charactertest_obj.move_speed(100003, -2147483648) not set before reading it.
 at gml_Object_charactertest_obj_Create_0 (line 7) - move_speed += 4;
gml_Object_charactertest_obj_Create_0 (line 7)

Comment: Can you show the code block where you've assigned the `move_speed`?

Comment: @LDLwarrior2 You must assign `move_speed` the value 4 **without** enabling the *Relative* tickbox. *Relative* means that the value is **added** to the current variable, otherwise the variable is **set** to that value. You cannot add values to non-existing variables.